# Code after for loop not executing when using await new Promise()

Tags: javascript, for-loop, async-await

I have an async function and with it I have a loop:

```
let z;
let step = 100;
for(z=0; z < (combinedData.length-1)/step; z += 1){
    // FURTHER CODE
}
```

Inside the loop there i sthis code:

```
let z;
let step = 100;
for(z=0; z < (combinedData.length-1)/step; z += 1){
    await new Promise((rs,rj)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            for(let x = 0; x < step; x++){
                let a = combinedData; // Array of 2522 elements
                let i = z*step + x;
                if(!(i < a.length))
                    return;
                // LONG CODE TO EXECUTE NOT PASTING BECAUSE IRRELEVANT I THINK
            }
            rs();
        });
    });
    console.log(`Showed ${z}`);
}
console.log('end');
```

And when I run it the result is:

```
Showed 1
Showed 2
...
Showed 24
```

Everything is right except for not showing 'end'.
I checked and there is no error in

```
//LONG CODE TO EXECUTE NOT PASTING BECAUSE IRRELEVANT
```

section so no worry about that.

I think, that error lay somewhere in

```
if(!(i<a.length))return;
```

but I don't know where and why. This statement is very important to not get
`TypeError` because of accessing `a[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code after your loop isn't execute, because you don't resolve or reject your created `Promise`.

You're right in the point, that this `if(!(i<a.length))return;` causes the problem, because with the return-statement you cancels the further execution of the function inside `setTimeout`, but you don't resolve your promise. So the await functions waits forever.

To simply solve your problem you can do following:

```
if(!(i<a.length)){
    return rs(); // Returns and resolves your created promise
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can give you an idea of how to properly code your loop:

```
async function delayedFunc(i, index) {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
  console.log(i, index);
}

async function main(array) {
  for (const [index, item] of array.entries()) {
    await delayedFunc(item, index);
  }
  console.log('Done!');
}

main([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

Comment: How can I get index of item without using `array.indexOf(item)` ? Is there a way?

Comment: @SkillGG I update the code to show index as well. You can code it in other type of loops. I just want to show how you can use async/await to achieve your goal.